# Table view with asynchronous image loading acting weird

Tags: ios

I'm having a table view with a background view and some text over it. I'm downloading the background from an url (in the below code it's hardcoded but I'll be having different url for each cell. To improve response , I'm using an image cache to hold downloaded images and loading the images asynchronously . I'm using a fade in animation for the image. Everything works fine except some weird behaviour. The first time, image loads fine. If I scroll , the image resizes to something else in each cell. Also if I stop scrolling , I can see the images reload randomly in each cell. Sometimes the image just disappears and reappears after a few seconds.

I'm not good enough in iOS to figure this out please help.

Here's my cell datasource method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.headerFrame];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return  cell;
    }
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but
    CustomSaloonCell *cell = (CustomSaloonCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomSaloonCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%ld" ,
                            (long)indexPath.row];
    if([self.cachedImages objectForKey:identifier] != nil){
      cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[cachedImages valueForKey:identifier]];
    } 
    else {
        char const * s = [identifier  UTF8String];
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(s, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/73/Shrekcharacter.jpg/220px-Shrekcharacter.jpg"];
            UIImage *img = nil;
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if ([theTableView indexPathForCell:cell].row == indexPath.row) {
                    [cachedImages setValue:img forKey:identifier];
                    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[cachedImages valueForKey:identifier]];
                    cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
                        cell.backgroundView.alpha = 1.0;
                    }];
                }
            });
        });
    }
    /********/
    cell.stylistName.text = [salonDetailsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"salonName"];
    cell.salonAddress.text = [salonDetailsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"salonAddress"];
    cell.delegateListener = self;
    cell.claimButton.frame =CGRectMake(494/2, 216/2, 120/2, 46.0/2.0);
    [cell.claimButton addTarget:self action:@selector(claimClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.claimButton setTitle:@"claim" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if([loginStatus isEqualToString:@"YES"]){
        [cell.claimButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:106.0/255.0 green:45.0/255.0 blue:118.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {

         [cell.claimButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    cell.claimButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.overlay.hidden = YES;
    for (NSIndexPath *selectedIndex in self.buttonStateArray){
        if([selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath]){
            [cell.claimButton setTitle:@"claimed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
               cell.claimButton.frame = CGRectMake(464/2-(30/2), 216/2, 180/2, 46.0/2.0);
            cell.overlay.hidden = NO;
            [cell.claimButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is the second most question on SO. You'll find valuable answers when searching more harder. ;)  The dominant problem is that you are capturing the _cell_ in your completion handler - which may be reused in the meantime the handler gets executed (instead, capture the _indexPath_ and obtain the cell again!). You should also use the appropriate methods for loading remote resources.

Answer (score 0):

Its good to use your own code for downloading and caching the images, but its not recommended b'cos there are many Highly optimized classes available which are doing it very smartly.
I preferred writing own code for Business logic,and to achieve performance using optimized library is Helpful.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

"SDWebImage" is fulfills your requirement, supports caching, asynchronous image downloading, completion block is also there where you can do animation stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try also [SmartStorage](http://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage). It automatically caches UIImage/NSData on disk or in memory.

That's its explanation diagram from GitHub:

[image]

There are code samples too. 
Good luck.